# Mouse wheel timestamp doesn't change

Tags: javascript, timestamp, dom-events

I would like to use the `timeStamp` property but it always has the value `-35852654.11` here is an example [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgyObG?editors=0011)

**EDIT:**

It looks like its a bug in `Chromium Version 48.0.2564.82 Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)` in Chrome and Firefox it works fine.

Comment: Seems to change every time for me.

Comment: It works on Chrome v52. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chromium maybe its a bug there